# How to fix dual boot after messing up with formatting and partitioning?

Tags: windows, multi-boot

I recently tried to reformat one of the partitions in my dual boot PC. I originally had XP and then installed 7 as a dual boot. Well, long story short, XP was having problems, so I reformatted the XP partition and lost my ability to dual boot.

I first tried [EasyBCD](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/EasyBCD), to fix the problem, but this made things worse. Upon restart I could no longer even load XP. Thus, I deleted the XP partition entirely in hopes to just have the Windows 7 partition and be able to boot.

Of course, this failed too and left me only able to boot from CD.

Is there any way I can fix this problem? I have tried commands in the command prompt off the 7 cd. I tried `bootrec /rebuildbcd` and got an "element not found" error. I then tried to make the partition active by using `diskpart`, but it give me a "the specified partition type is not valid for this operation" error.

Given CarpeNoctem's [answer below](https://superuser.com/questions/109434/how-to-fix-dual-boot-after-messing-up-with-formatting-and-partitioning/109435#109435) I did `bootsect /nt60 ALL`. This completed successfully, but I'm still getting:

> Verifying DMI Pool Data ......
>   Boot from CD/DVD: DISK BOOT FAILURE, INSERT SYSTEM DISK AND PRESS ENTER

I tried `bootrec /fixmbr` and a reboot, but still the same error. I've tried to erase the BCD files but it says access is denied on D: (my second partition) and it says it cannot find the specified file in C: (my erased partition). Next I did `bootrec /rebuildbcd` again, and it identified 1 Windows installation, `C:\Windows`, just like `bootrec /scanos` reports.

That's where I'm at.

Answer (score 1):

Boot off a windows 7 disk and select "Repair your computer" then choose "command prompt". Now cd into the boot dir and run:

```
bootsect /nt60 ALL
```

Report back.

Comment: Thank you for the help. I did that and my bootcode was successfully updated on all target volumes. How should I proceed from here? Sorry. I'm not great with command prompt.

Comment: Since there's no additional OSes installed at this time then there's no reason to manually edit the BCD or anything like that. How do you fair on reboot?

Comment: I still get the stupid Verifying DMI Pool Data ......
Boot from CD/DVD:
DISK BOOT FAILURE, INSERT SYSTEM DISK AND PRESS ENTER

Comment: Sounds like the MBR might have been borked somehow. The bootsect is probably good so let's try "bootrec /fixmbr" and a reboot. If that doesn't work then the BCD is next.

Comment: I did it and it completed successfully. But I'm still getting that lovely BOOT DISK FAILURE error. Thanks so much for helping me.

Comment: I've tried to erase the BCD files but it says access is denied on D: (my second partition) and it says it cannot find the specified file in C: (my erased partition). I wouldn't even mind just making it one partition again, if it means I get to retain my files.

Comment: Back in the command prompt, if you cd into the boot dir and do a directory listing..do you see the file named bcd? If so let's get rid of it and recreate it. "attrib bcd -s -h -r" then do "ren d:\boot\bcd bcd.old", then recreate it with: "bootrec /RebuildBcd". Let me know how that goes.

Comment: There is no bcd file. Do I need to create one?

Comment: Yes, use the "bootrec /RebuildBcd" command. Hopefully that will recreate it.

Comment: I did and it identified 1 windows installation. C:\Windows. When it asked if I want to add the installation to the boot list, I said Y. It then just said "element not found." Any clues as to what might cause that?

Comment: Weird stuff. What's the results of "bootrec /scanos"?

Comment: It found 1- C:\Windows. I wonder if it might have something to do with the way that I deleted the other partition? It is currently extended and unassigned to a volume. I'm just speculating. This is very frustrating. Thanks.

Comment: Yeah, at this point personally I would probably try simplifying the partitions. Get it so that you have just the valid windows 7 primary partition using all available space. Make sure the partition type is correct and the active flag is set (if it needs to be). Once that is done I would redo the "bootrec.exe /fixmbr",
"bootrec.exe /fixboot","bootrec.exe /rebuildbcd" commands and see if that works. Sorry man best of luck to you. *Also, might want to ghost the drive as a backup*.

Comment: Ugh. This is just too frustrating. I'll prolly just back up all my files and completely reformat. Thanks so much for all your help!

Answer (score 0):

If you changed the numbers of partitions, Windows won't work any more, since it uses partition numbers internally.

But since you are on Windows 7, see this article - 
[How to Run a Startup Repair in Windows 7](http://www.sevenforums.com/tutorials/681-startup-repair.html):

> Startup Repair is a Windows 7 system
>   recovery tool that can fix certain
>   problems, such as missing or damaged
>   system files (ex: MBR boot file), that
>   might prevent Windows from starting
>   correctly. This will show you how to
>   run Startup Repair to allow it to scan
>   your Windows 7 computer for a startup
>   problem and try to fix it so your
>   computer can start correctly.